# What is the best way to style the selected(clicked) item

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to style the selected column of the following HTML code

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item starter">
            <a href="#/starter">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/starter.jpg" alt="starter">
            </a>
             <h2><a href="#/starter">Starter</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#/salads">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/salads.jpg" alt="salads">
            </a>
             <h2><a href="#/salads">Salads</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#/main">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/main.jpg" alt="main">
            </a>
             <h2><a href="#/main">Main</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#/dessert">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/desserts.jpg" alt="desserts">
            </a>
             <h2><a href="#/dessert">Desserts</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

I have 4 columns as above, when user selects(clicks) one of the column, i want to highlight it with some style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Add `main-menu` class and `active` class

**JQUERY**

```
$('.main-menu div').on('click',function(){
  $('div').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
    background-color:green;
  }
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/uVfokPUMgH)